# Optimize route by distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, here-api

I am building a Here Maps based web application.
Its main features include the ability to upload a spreadsheet file (.xls, .xlsx) to the server and plan a route with the addresses in the file, up to 500 waypoints.

Of course, these waypoints aren't any way in an optimized order, so I'd like to let the user click on a "OPTIMIZE ROUTE" button and that would optimize it by distance.

For example if the file has these three addresses:

1. New York
2. San Francisco
3. Long Island

The route by default would be to go from NY to SF, then back to LI.

The application would check the distances and reorder the waypoints array in a way like this:

NY -> LI -> SF

**My question:**
Is there a built in route optimization function in Here Maps, or should I write my own?

Comment: I really wanted to get this done using HERE Maps and was [searching for an easy solution](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhere-api%5D+optimize), but unfortunately, it seems we'll have to turn to Google Maps, as apparently the solution there is as simple as [adding `optimize:true` to the request query](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#OptimizeWaypoints)

Comment: **UPDATE** Okay, it looks like HERE Maps might actually have something like what we need: [Waypoints Sequence for a Car](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing_waypoints/sequence-waypoints-car-route). Not sure why is it buried that deep into the examples section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Matrix Routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-matrix-of-routes.html). This will calculate the "real" distance between each of N x M locations. With this information, you have reduced the issue to the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Of course, the TSP is NP-complete, so you can't be certain you've got the optimal answer unless you use a brute force algorithm.

Personally I'd look at a nearest neighbour solution - quick, very simple to code and usually returns a "reasonable", if not optimal solution. You can update to more complex algorithms as necessary:

Pseudo-code below:

1. Start at point A
2. Matrix routing request to all remaining points.
3. Find nearest, this becomes the next Waypoint
4. Repeat from step 2.

Comment: Once again, thanks. This is by far the easiest method I've found.

Comment: Nice to see your answers for here-maps. could you please help me with one maps issue here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249057/how-to-display-loading-icon-while-rendering-markers-on-the-map

Comment: I think url to Matrix Routing API changed, check: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-matrix-of-routes.html

Answer (score 0):

This is called the travelling salesmen problem.

You need to have a table of the distance from any place to any other place you support.

Once you have that you can use any generic travelling salesmen algorithm.

Be warned that they are very famously slow.