# How to display Loading Icon while rendering Markers on the MAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, here-api

Rightnow i'm developing an application where i have to display huge number of markers on the map roughly (30K to 50K).right now while rendering the map it is taking time to render whole points so i would like to add an loading gif icon while Navteq Map renders the pointsso that user will be aware of that map is rendering the points.

I'm using latest Nokia(Here)- Maps API version `2.5.3`.
i have tried with `transitionstart` and `transistionend` events but it is not showing my GIF icon but if i only handle the `tranisionstart` event  then the ICON willbe shown.but if i handle both events it would display the icon, i'm suspecting that it is due to start and end events are attached sidebyside.

I tried this:

**JavaScript:**

```
  map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // Initial center and zoom level of the map

    center: [51.410496, 5.459197],
    zoomLevel: ZoomLevel,
    components: [
        // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),
        infoBubbles
    ]
 });
 map.addListener("transitionstart", function () {
    ChangeProgressGif(true);
 });

 map.addListener("transitionend", function () {
        ChangeProgressGif(false);
    });


function ChangeProgressGif(progressFlag)
{       
    if (progressFlag)
        document.getElementById("ProgressIcon").style.visibility = "visible";
    else
        document.getElementById("ProgressIcon").style.visibility =  "hidden";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="Images\\Resources\\LoadingGIF.gif" id="ProgressIcon"/>
```

**NOTE:** i have tried BaseMapChangeStart and BaseMapChangeEnd events also but none of them worked. any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** after trying the @Jason solution it is even taking some time to render the points after the `CluterProvider` state is changed to `ready`.

and as mentioned in comments i tried with state `Clustered` as well, but state `Clustered` is coming before the `ReadyState`.

**Console Output from chrome:**

[image]

from the console i observed that there are many ready states and can we identify which one is the last ready state so that we can stop/hide the loading icon.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Checking if clustering is complete**

You probably want to add an **observer** to the `state` property of the cluster provider instead:

```
function clusterDataPoints(data) {
  clusterProvider = new nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider(map, {
    eps: 16,
    minPts: 1,
    dataPoints: data
  });

  clusterProvider.addObserver("state", 
    function (obj, key, newValue, oldValue) { 
      console.log(newValue);
    }
  );
  clusterProvider.cluster();
}
```

The [ClusterProvider](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider.html) will change state to `STATE_READY` whenever clustering is complete.

**Adding a loading icon**

To add a "Loading" icon, you should add a custom map control like this:

```
function extend(B, A) {
  function I() {}
  I.prototype = A.prototype;
  B.prototype = new I();
  B.prototype.constructor = B;
}

function HtmlControl (html, id) {
  nokia.maps.map.component.Component.call(this);
  this.init(html, id);
}

extend(HtmlControl,
    nokia.maps.map.component.Component);


HtmlControl.prototype.init = function (html, id) {
  that = this;
  that.id = id
  that.set('node',  document.createElement('div'));  
  that.node.innerHTML = html;
};

HtmlControl.prototype.getId = function () { 
  return 'HtmlControl.' + this.id;
};

HtmlControl.prototype.attach = function (map) {
  map.getUIContainer().appendChild(this.node);
};

HtmlControl.prototype.detach = function (display) {
  map.getUIContainer().removeChild(this.node);
};
```

It can be added to the map like this:

```
htmlControl = new HtmlControl(
     '<div class=\'loader\' style=\'width:540px; height:334px; display:block\'></div>', 'Loader');
  map.components.add(htmlControl);
```

and styled using CSS:

```
<style>
  .loader {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-image: url(img/loading.gif);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
```

You would then just need to `add()` or `remove()` the html control to display the loading gif.

Comment: could you please also have a look at my another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224749/how-to-display-markers-huge-numbers-on-a-map-which-has-been-logically-divided

Comment: Works great, but map renders the points even after `ClusterProvider` state is changed to `ready`.as mentioned here (link in your answer) `This constant indicates a state which an instance of ClusterProvider enters when it has determined clusters and noise points and their representation for display on the map. Note that when this state is set, clusters and noise points may not be visible on the map yet. The rendering engine needs some additional time to draw them on the map.` can't we identify the complete rendering time? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using  [STATE_CLUSTERED](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider.html#topic-apiref__ClusterProvider-STATE_CLUSTERED) rather than STATE_READY if it helps.

Comment: yes , i verified that too but it is coming before the `ready state`.i observed that there are mutilple `ready states` can we identify the which one is last, please check my edited question.

Comment: Rendering is asynchronous. The ClusterProvider extends Provider. You could set up an event listener and listen for the response event. However it is unusual to wait for this as the map should be responsive after READY

Comment: If you insist on forcing the user to stare at a loading screen, you could always start a timer to clear the gif and reset it if another READY has arrived, but it rather misses the point of rendering the clusters asynchronously

Comment: yes.but i'm not blocking the user to wait till the map renders all the points just i'm showing the loading icon as small image some where on the map so that user awares that rendering is going on.could you please show me how to subscribe to the Provider event?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49261/discussion-between-sudhakar-tillapudi-and-jason-fox)

Comment: Thanks Jason, Ready state is working fine, i'm able to display the progressicon on the map now. Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: hi sir, could you please take a look at my another question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592829/markers-are-missing-suddenly-while-rendering-on-here-maps