# Markers are missing suddenly while rendering on here maps 2.5.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, here-api

I have developed an application where it displays collection of markeres on the navteq map.when i was working with `navteq maps 2.2.3` everything was working fine, but as `Navteq maps 2.2.3` does not support for `Asynchronous behaviour` i have switched to `HereMaps 2.5.3` which supports `Asynchronous` behaviour.

Now after switching to latest version i'm facing one strange problem. that is  while rendering the markers on the map suddenly already rendered points/markers(some points) gets disappeared.this problem happens some times and if again i try to generate markeres on the map it works fine.

so i think i need to handle some Display events properly before rendering.

sample images are as below:

**Image 1: Properly Rendered markers**

[image: Properly Rendered Markers]

**Image 2: Rendered but missing some points**

[image]

**MyCode is as below:**

the below function is responsible for displaying the markers on the map.

```
function displayAllPoints(arrLightPointCoordinats, totalLightPoints, selectedSegmentId,
                                        totalSegmentsCount, segmentColorcode) 
{
    var MyTheme1 = function () {
    };
    segmentColorcode = segmentColorcode.substring(2, segmentColorcode.length - 1);
    MyTheme1.prototype.getNoisePresentation = function (dataPoint) {
        var markerLightPoint = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(dataPoint, {
            icon: new nokia.maps.gfx.BitmapImage("..//Images//Lightpoint//" + segmentColorcode + ".png"),
            anchor: {
                x: 12,
                y: 12
            }
        });
        return markerLightPoint;
    };
    MyTheme1.prototype.getClusterPresentation = function (data) {
        var markerLightPoint = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(data.getBounds().getCenter(), {
            icon: new nokia.maps.gfx.BitmapImage("..//Images//SegmentController/" + 
                                    segmentColorcode + ".png", null, 66, 65),
            text: data.getSize(),
            zIndex: 2,
            anchor: {
                x: 12,
                y: 12
            }
        });
        return markerLightPoint;
    };
    var indexes = new nokia.maps.clustering.Index();
    var lightpointsDataSet1 = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < totalLightPoints; i++) {
        lightpointsDataSet1[i] = { latitude: arrLightPointCoordinats[i][0],
        longitude: arrLightPointCoordinats[i][1], title: 'LightPoint ' + (i + 1) };
        indexes.add([arrLightPointCoordinats[i][0], arrLightPointCoordinats[i][1]]);
    }
    var ClusterProvider = nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider,
        theme = new MyTheme1(),
        clusterProvider = new ClusterProvider(map, {
            eps: 0.00000000001,
            minPts: 1000000,
            strategy: nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider.STRATEGY_DENSITY_BASED,
            index: indexes,
            theme: theme,
            dataPoints: []
        });
    clusterProvider.addAll(lightpointsDataSet1);
    clusterProvider.cluster();
    map.update(-1, 0);
    //set zoom level here

    setCenterAndZoom(13, arrSegmentControllerIds[0]);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I use the Display Ready Event, before starting the Clustering:

```
        map.addListener("displayready", function()
        {
            mapContainer.style.display = 'block';

            // load the photos as cluster data
            url = "http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/res/clustering/photos.js";
            script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        });

        onDataReceive = function(data)
        {
            displayAllPoints(data);
        }

        function displayAllPoints(arrLightPointCoordinates) 
        {           {
            var MyTheme1 = function (){};
            MyTheme1.prototype.getNoisePresentation = function (dataPoint) {
                var markerLightPoint = new nokia.maps.map.Marker(dataPoint, {
                    icon: new nokia.maps.gfx.BitmapImage("/res/marker_red.png"),
                    anchor: {
                        x: 12,
                        y: 12
                    }
                });
                return markerLightPoint;
            };

            MyTheme1.prototype.getClusterPresentation = function (data) {
                var markerLightPoint = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(data.getBounds().getCenter(), {
                    icon: new nokia.maps.gfx.BitmapImage("/res/marker_green.png", null, 66, 65),
                    text: data.getSize(),
                    zIndex: 2,
                    anchor: {
                        x: 12,
                        y: 12
                    }
                });
                return markerLightPoint;
            };
/*              
            var indexes = new nokia.maps.clustering.Index();
            var lightpointsDataSet1 = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < totalLightPoints; i++) {
                lightpointsDataSet1[i] = { latitude: arrLightPointCoordinats[i][0],
                longitude: arrLightPointCoordinats[i][1], title: 'LightPoint ' + (i + 1) };
                indexes.add([arrLightPointCoordinats[i][0], arrLightPointCoordinats[i][1]]);
            }
*/
            var ClusterProvider = nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider,
                theme = new MyTheme1(),
                clusterProvider = new ClusterProvider(map, {
                    eps: 0.00000000001,
                    minPts: 1000000,
                    strategy: nokia.maps.clustering.ClusterProvider.STRATEGY_DENSITY_BASED,
                    // index: indexes,
                    theme: theme,
                    dataPoints: []
                });
            clusterProvider.addAll(arrLightPointCoordinates);
            clusterProvider.cluster();
            map.update(-1, 0);
            //set zoom level here
            // setCenterAndZoom(13, arrSegmentControllerIds[0]);
        }
```

Hope that helps. Also you can check out the newest version 2.5.4.

Best,

Dom

Comment: ThankYou verymuch for your answer , let me try and see.