# Loading a KML file - is there a limit to the number of points?

Tags: here-api

I was loading 6,000 points of interests from a single KML file but it's not loading.  What I did is to split it in 4 KML files.  It loads but it's quite slow.  My questions are:

1. Is there a limit on the number of points I can put in the KML file?
2. Is there a code to speed it up?  I just used these codes to load the KML files:

   kmlManager.parseKML("./SOURCE_KML/Part1.KML")
   kmlManager2.parseKML("./SOURCE_KML/Part2.KML", onParsed);
   kmlManager3.parseKML("./SOURCE_KML/Part3.kml", onParsed);
   kmlManager4.parseKML("./SOURCE_KML/Part4.kml", onParsed);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there must be some limit to the number of points read/displayed from a KML file. Since you haven't mentioned how large your file(s) are and what the time taken for each stage of processing  it is difficult to tell where in the chain of actions your file or files are being so slow.

It could be any  of the following:

- Network connection/download of the KML. Speed is based on your network.
- KML processing as done by the HERE Maps JavaScript Library. Speed is based on the browser used.
- Actual rendering of Points on the map as done by the HERE Maps JavaScript Library. Speed is based on the browser used.

Programmatically there is nothing you can do about point 1. If it takes time to load then so be it. This is basically a user interface issue (managing expectations), your technique of chunking up the data and loading a smaller files is probably a good one. Combine this with a [wait icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249057/how-to-display-loading-icon-while-rendering-markers-on-the-map) to show the user that something is happening.

Regarding point 2 - you should consider whether KML is the correct (i.e flexible) format for processing your data. Other file formats could be shorter or could hold your data more concisely. Maybe you need to use some custom processing prior to display. [This example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#kml-choropleth-map__index) uses AJAX and the KML Manager [parse()](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.kml.Manager.html#topic-apiref__Manager-parse-method) method prior to displaying the file. This allows customization of the KML prior to rendering.

Regarding point 3 - there **is** something you can do about this - adding and rendering 6000 Markers directly is bound to take time. This can be alleviated by **marker clustering** - i.e. only rendering a fraction of the markers at any one time.

Consider the data visualisation [KML Earthquake example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/data-visualization/display-data-on-map.html) from developer.here.com - the example blindly renders a given KML file with approximately 300 points. At the size shown below the points overlap and can't be easily distinguished anyway:

[image: KML Earthquake]

Now if you want to modify the rendered result it would be better to preprocess or use another format such as GeoJSON, and customize the response. An example combining GeoJSON parsing and marker clustering can be found in the [HERE Maps community examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#geojson-parser__load-geojson-earthquake-cluster-data-using-ajax). This renders a fraction of the data and hence displays the data file more quickly.

[image: KML Earthquake Clustered]

Obviously if you have 6000 points rather than 300 the improvement will be even more noticeable.